# StyleSheet file in output folder

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

I'm new in reactJs and I'm using webpack-dev-server to compile and check my code, the problem is that when I add a stylesheet to the sources as an imported file in the result everything is shown well and also in the output folder with the plugin I've imported the bundle.js file update but there is no sign of stylesheet file
My question is that what happened to the css file ? is that necessary to be there? or the styles are composed by the output js file? because when i moved the file it works fine again without any problem.
tnx

Comment: Consider adding your web pack config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In production you probably wants to include all your CSS in one bundle file minifiying the result and exclude all CSS files not minified you used for actual development.

To do this you could use a CSS Loader, there are several options, one could be:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader

An interesting article, it should help you to get started:
https://medium.com/trabe/multiple-css-bundles-with-webpack-75f263095f09

Comment: Tnx for the answer, of course I'm using Style and css loader but my question is  it is need that i have the css file in side of my js file in product folder or not ?

Comment: In the production folder you need to place only the bundled CSS file, the CSS you use for dev usually it is not included in the output folder. I edited my answer, please let me know if it is more helpful now.